# Split the long NodeJs webserver File

Tags: node.js, web-deployment

i have a long webserver.js file for my NodeApplication and basically whats it do is
it it has an express module to show static pages and also some function to process GET and POST Request ..

these GET and POST request will internally call some REST Service to fetch Data and pass the RESULT to browser so the REST API is not exposed to public ..

```
    var express = require('express');
    var request = require('request');
    var compression = require('compression');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var app = express();
    var util = require("util");
    async = require("async");



    app.use(compression());
    app.use(bodyParser.json({}));
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


    require('./node_scripts/session.js')(app);
    var Url = require('./node_scripts/ServiceUrls.js');


    //REDIRECT TO PUBLIC DIRECTORY
    app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


    //GET TEMPLATES FOR FORM
    app.get('/Templates', function(req, res) {
        var MyJsonData = {
            AccessToken: req.session.AccessToken || 0
        };
        console.log(MyJsonData);
        request({
            url: Url.UserService + 'GetTemplates', //URL to hit
            method: 'POST',
            json: MyJsonData

        }, function(error, response, body) {
            if (error) {

                res.send("dummytext");
                res.end();
                console.log("/Templates (send dummy data) ->" + error);
            } else {
                console.log("/Templates REST Response");
                console.log(response.statusCode, body);
                res.send(body);
                res.end();
            }


        })
    });

app.get('/AnotherRequest', function(req, res) {
        });
..
..
..
app.get('/AnotherNthRequest', function(req, res) {
        });
```

So how cann i split the file so that some request can be grouped into seperate js files and it will be easier for developing

im completely new to NodejS . ya but i have experience is PHP which wont help me in this case

Comment: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: You have to use routers for that.

Comment: thank u... router was new to me ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **express router** for this purpose.

Below code is a simple demonstration of how your code can be modified.

Your main file is split into three parts

---

1. server.js (Just File names, use your convention)

---

```
 var express = require('express');
 var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 var app = express();

 app.use(bodyParser.json({}));
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
     extended: true
 }));

 //REDIRECT TO PUBLIC DIRECTORY
 app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

 // Send request to the routes
var router = require('./routes')(app, express);

// Append the router 
app.use('/', router);
```

---

Put your route handling here.

2. routes.js

---

```
var myController = require('./controller');


module.exports = function (app, express) {

    // Create route handlers
    var router = express.Router();

    router.route('/Templates')
        //GET TEMPLATES FOR FORM
        .get(function (req, res) {
            myController.myFunction(req,res);
        });

    router.route('/AnotherRequest')
        .get(function (req, res) {});

    ..
    ..
    ..

    router.route('/AnotherNthRequest')
        .get(function (req, res) {});

    return router;
};
```

---

Put your logic here.

3. controller.js

---

```
 var request = require('request');


 var Url = require('./node_scripts/ServiceUrls.js');

 exports.myFunction = function (req, res) {

     var MyJsonData = {
         AccessToken: req.session.AccessToken || 0
     };
     console.log(MyJsonData);
     request({
         url: Url.UserService + 'GetTemplates', //URL to hit
         method: 'POST',
         json: MyJsonData

     }, function (error, response, body) {
         if (error) {

             res.send("dummytext");
             res.end();
             console.log("/Templates (send dummy data) ->" + error);
         } else {
             console.log("/Templates REST Response");
             console.log(response.statusCode, body);
             res.send(body);
             res.end();
         }


     })


 };
```

Comment: Thats was an excellent solution . i already implemented using express.Router(); but in a more easy way like 
var objApiServer = require('./node_scripts/ApiServer'); 
app.use('/', objApiServer);
where ApiServer has some GET Request management

Answer (score 0):

We can take advantage of the express instance (var app), remember express supports the following routing methods that correspond to HTTP methods: get, post, put, head, delete etc. What this means is that we can pass the express instance as a parameter of a function which handles the routing for us.

We can also take the concept further by separating our callbacks from our HTTP methods (remember routes have the format app.VERB('path', callback)), so we will also house our callbacks in separate file.

We can use exports.**CALLBACKNAME** to expose individual callbacks and module.exports to expose our full routing file to the server module. Hence:

```
//templates.controller.js (this is the file name for example)

exports.tempHandler = function(req, res) {
    var MyJsonData = {
        AccessToken: req.session.AccessToken || 0
    };
    console.log(MyJsonData);
    request({
        url: Url.UserService + 'GetTemplates', //URL to hit
        method: 'POST',
        json: MyJsonData

    }, function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) {

            res.send("dummytext");
            res.end();
            console.log("/Templates (send dummy data) ->" + error);
        } else {
            console.log("/Templates REST Response");
            console.log(response.statusCode, body);
            res.send(body);
            res.end();
        }


    })
};
```

template.router.js

```
// we first export the file which houses our callbacks
var templates = require('../controllers/template.controller.js');

// the app parameter represents the express instance (var app)
// we provide it as a parameter and manipulate it in the file

module.exports = function(app) {
    // Here you go, short and clean
    app.get('/Templates', templates.tempHandler);
    // and your other routes
};
```

And then in the webserver.js, you just add the following line in place of your routes:

```
require('./app/routes/template.router')(app);
```

This is just a basic example of it, hope it helps.